# Escape for str in Python

Tags: python

Wow, this should be so simple, but it' just not working.
I need to inset a "\" into a string (for a Bash command), but escaping just doesn't work.

```
>>> a = 'testing'
>>> b = a[:3] + '\' + a[3:]
    >>> File "<stdin>", line 1
    >>> b = a[:3] + '\' + a[3:]
                              ^
   >>>SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> b = a[:3] + '\\' + a[3:]
>>> b
'tes\\ting'
>>> sys.version
'2.7 (r27:82500, Sep 16 2010, 18:02:00) \n[GCC 4.5.1 20100907 (Red Hat 4.5.1-3)]'
```

The first error is understandable and expexted. The end quote is being eaten, and the interpreter barfs. 
However, the second example should work. Why is there two slashes?

Python 2.7

Thanks,

Edit: Thanks Greg. It was a problem with working at the interpreter and not using repr(b). Python was working correctly, but I wasn't looking at the correct version of the output.

Comment: Short answer: The second example **is** working. The Python interactive shell usually outputs the representation of evaluating the previous line of input so it's showing you the `repr(b)`. Try `print b` instead.

Comment: "Why is there two slashes?" For the same reason that there is "\n" in `sys.version` instead of it continuing on the next line. :)

Comment: "with working at the interpreter and not using repr(b)" Other way around: an issue with *using* `repr` (implicitly).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are being misled by Python's output. Try:

```
>>> a = "test\\ing"
>>> print(a)
test\ing
>>> print(repr(a))
'test\\ing'
>>> a
'test\\ing'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want double slashes because the shell will escape \ again, use a raw string:

```
b = a[:3] + r'\\' + a[3:]
```

Comment: That puts four slashes in: 'tes\\\\ting'

Comment: @fandingo: well, I understood he wanted double slashes because the shell would escape \again...

Comment: The OP says in his question that he's trying to insert a single backslash into the string (and what he did *was* working, he just doesn't realize it).

Answer (score 1):

`'tes\\ting'` is correct, but you are viewing the `repr` output for the string, which will always show escape characters.

```
>>> print 'tes\\ting'
tes\ting
```

Answer (score 1):

The second example is correct. There are two slashes because you are printing the *Python representation* of the string.

If you want to see the actual string, call `print a`.

Answer (score 0):

b is fine in the second example, you see two slashes because you're printing the representation of b, so slashes are escaped in it too.

```
>>> b
'tes\\ting'
>>> print b
tes\ting
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's quoting the backslash again when it shows you the representation of the string (in such a way that you could paste it in and get the string with an escaped backslash).

If you print the string, you'll see there's only one in the actual string.

```
>>> print "hello\\world"
hello\world
```