# Escaping escape sequence in Python

Tags: python, escaping, unicode-escapes

I am kind of new to python. Goal is to execute a shell command using subprocess parse & retrive the printed output from shell. The execution errors out as shown in the sample output msg below. Also shown below is the sample code snippet

Code snippet:

```
testStr = "cat tst.txt | grep Location | sed -e '/.*Location: //g' "
print "testStr = "+testStr
testStrOut = subprocess.Popen([testStr],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Output:

```
testStr = cat tst.txt | grep Location | sed -e '/.*Location: //g' 
cat: tst.txt: No such file or directory
sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unknown command: `/'
```

Is there a workaround or a function that could be used ?

Appreciate your help
Thanks

Comment: give subprocess the full path of the file "tst.txt".

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your main error is not python related. To be more precise, there are 3 of them:

1. You forgot to `import subprocess`.
2. It should be `sed -e 's/.*Location: //g'`. You wrote `///g` instead of `s///g`.
3. `tst.txt` does not exist.

Comment: Thanks- That was one mistake. Found it in the mean time. Also the following link answered to the question on escaping '\r' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392176/escape-for-str-in-python.

Answer (score 1):

You should be passing testStr directly as the first argument, rather than enclosing it in a list. See [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), the paragraph that starts "On Unix, with shell=True: ...".